# Categorical Distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

Suppose I want to do calculations with a random variable $X$ that has a simple [categorical distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_distribution) (a.k.a generalised Bernoulli distribution or discrete distribution).

I was expecting to be able to work with a distribution "symbolically". That is, I was expecting that there would be a function like `CategoricalDistribution`, that we could use like this.

```
distX = CategoricalDistribution[{1/3, 1/2, 1/6}];
```

But no distributions in [tutorial/DiscreteDistributions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/DiscreteDistributions.html) looked like they were suitable. An example of how the distribution would be used would be

```
{Probability[x == 0, x \[Distributed] dist],
 Probability[x == 1, x \[Distributed] dist],
 Probability[x == 2, x \[Distributed] dist]}
```

would output

> ```
> {1/3, 1/2, 1/6}
> ```

In this particular case, we can do a workaround, by doing

```
dist = TransformedDistribution[
  x1 + x2, {x1 \[Distributed] BernoulliDistribution[1/2], 
   x2 \[Distributed] BernoulliDistribution[1/3]}]
```

Unfortunately, this is not always possible, even with only 3 possible outcomes. For example, we cannot simulate `CategoricalDistribution[{1/2, 0, 1/2}]` like this, as we cannot have independent Bernoulli random variables that behave like this.

I was hoping the categorical distribution might be a special case of another distribution. Especially the `MultinomialDistribution` with 1 as its first argument looks useful, but I cannot transform that distribution into a distribution that gives an integer. Again it seems like I am missing a function like `CategoricalDistribution` to do so. To give an example

```
Position[RandomVariate@MultinomialDistribution[1, {1/2, 0, 1/2}], 
  1][[1, 1]]
```

"has the right distribution", but unfortunately I cannot use `Position` inside `TransformedDistribution`.

I am aware of functions like `RandomChoice`, but really I only want to do manipulations on distributions. Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: [Strongly related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28972/4330)

Comment: I suppose `dist = ProbabilityDistribution[Piecewise[{{1/2, y == 0}, {0, y == 1}, {1/2, y == 2}} ], {y, 0, 2, 1}]`, or `dist = ProbabilityDistribution[Switch[y, 0, 1/2, 1, 0, 2, 1/2], {y, 0, 2, 1}];` do pretty much what I want. Maybe I should delete/close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: `CategoricalDistribution` is a built-in symbol as of Version 12.1 in 2020. Much of the requested functionality is incorporated. However since *categories* are inherently non-numeric, functions such as `Mean` are not implemented for categorical distributions.

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CategoricalDistribution.html

Answer (score 9):

[`EmpiricalDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/EmpiricalDistribution.html) can assign probabilities to each element in a set of discrete values:

Here's an example:

```
In[1]:= d = EmpiricalDistribution[{1/3, 1/2, 1/6} -> {1, 2, 3}];

In[2]:= Mean[d]
Out[2]= 11/6

In[3]:= PDF[d, x]
Out[3]= 1/3 Boole[1 == x] + 1/2 Boole[2 == x] + 1/6 Boole[3 == x]

In[4]:= CDF[d, x]
Out[4]= 1/3 Boole[1 <= x] + 1/2 Boole[2 <= x] + 1/6 Boole[3 <= x]

In[5]:= RandomVariate[d, 10]
Out[5]= {1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1}

In[6]:= Probability[x == 1, x \[Distributed] d]
Out[6]= 1/3
```

Comment: This is community wiki, i.e. people are welcome to edit and improve it.

Comment: Wolfram should probably mention "categorical distributions" in the help page for `EmpiricalDistribution`, they are equivalent as far as I can tell.

Comment: @A.G. Why don't you suggest it?  There's a give feedback button [at the bottom of the page](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/EmpiricalDistribution.html).  Maybe even link back here to prove that it's not easy to find.

Comment: Done. Thanks for suggesting it.